# NullPointerException on Button

Tags: android

I have an android app with a Fragment, it has a button inside which leads to an Activity when clicked. When I ran the app on my device, it returned an error. Im just confused cause everything seems to be correct but then it returns this error. Please help me spot my erros. Thank you!

```
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096): Process: com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider, PID: 32096
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider
 com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider.Portfolio_AddImageToConsultation}: 
 java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2693)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2758)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:177)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1448)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5942)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1400)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1195)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider.Portfolio_AddImageToConsultation.onCreate(Portfolio_AddImageToConsultation.java:86)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6289)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
 06-22 17:32:58.103: E/AndroidRuntime(32096):   ... 10 more
```

This is my code

```
public class Portfolio extends Fragment {
Button cam;
Intent addEvent;
public Portfolio() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_portfolio,
    container, false);

    cam = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.camerabutton);
    cam.setOnClickListener(addbutton);

    return view;
}
OnClickListener addbutton = new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        addEvent = new Intent(getActivity(), Portfolio_AddImageToConsultation.class);
        startActivity(addEvent);
    }
};
```

This is my layout

```
 <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:baselineAligned="false"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >
<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello_world" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/camerabutton"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Sign Up" />
```

Comment: Where are you calling this Fragment?It seems you are using this Fragment class as Launcher which is not correct.You should use Fragment inside Activity.

Comment: Yup, I have a FragmentManager in another Activity class

Answer (score 0):

Is the layout that you pasted code here is `fragment_portfolio`? Because you have to inflate the layout with the button, and not any other layout. Also try to remove `tools:context=".MainActivity"` may be it will help.

Comment: Yes that's fragment_portfolio :/ I tried removing tools:context then it gave me this error
06-22 21:01:05.040: E/AndroidRuntime(24226): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider/com.samsung.android.example.helloaccessoryprovider.Portfolio_AddImageToConsultation}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem! Turns out I was using a different layout in Patien_AddImageToConsultation class that wasn't in the android application